# Yet another coin flipping problem

Tags: code-golf, math, probability-theory

**Problem**

Starting with a set of 10 coins at the start where all coins are tails up, and given n number of integers \$x_1, x_2, x_3... x_n\$ representing n rounds of coin flipping.

At each round, we randomly flip \$x_i\$ number of coins at random. i.e Coins that were heads become tails, and vice versa. Within each round, every coin can be flipped at most once, i.e no repeats.

**Objective**
Write the shortest function that takes as input a list of integers, and calculates the expected number of heads at the end of all rounds.

Assume that the inputs will always correct, i.e every element is between 0 to 10.

Example 1:

```
# 3 coins chosen at random were flipped over one round, hence E(Heads) = 3
Input = [3]
Output = 3
```

Example 2:

```
# 5 coins chosen at random were flipped in the first round
# At the second round, only 1 was random flipped with 50% chance of 
# picking a head/tail. E(Heads) = 0.5*6 + 0.5*4

# Hence E(Heads) = 5
Input = [5, 1]
Output = 5
```

Comment: By "We randomly flip x_i number of coins in sequence in each of the n rounds", do you mean that a random x_i-size-subset of the 10 coins (so a coin can't be flipped more than once in the same round), and they are each flipped once? Or do you mean that x_i times, a coin is chosen and flipped (so a coin might be flipped more than once in the same round)?

Comment: That is a good catch. Coins are flipped without repeats within each round. Will refine the question to reflect this.

Comment: This seems clear now so I've reopened this.  Nice challenge, thanks for sticking with it. (btw if you want to reply to someone you can use `@<their name>` at the beginning so they will be notified)

Comment: @WheatWizard thanks for the inputs as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
r=0
for c in input():r+=c-r*c/5.
print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8jWgCstv0ghWSEzD4gKSks0NK2KtG2TdYu0kvVN9bgKijLzShSK/v@PNtVRMIwFAA)

Let \$Z_i, 1 \le i \le 10 \$ be random variables indicating the state of the \$i\$-th coin after all flips, \$1\$ for heads and \$0\$ for tails. The number we are interested in is:

$$
E \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{10} Z_i \right] = \sum_{i=1}^{10} E \left[ Z_i \right] = 10 E\left[ Z_1 \right]
$$

(We can do these two equalities because the expected value is linear and all \$Z_i\$ are identically distributed)

This means it is enough to compute the expected value for a single coin, which leads to the following program, where the formula can be simplified to the above:

```python
r=0.0
for c in input():r=r*(10-c)/10+(1-r)*c/10
print r*10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8jWQM@AKy2/SCFZITMPiApKSzQ0rYpsi7Q0DA10kzX1DQ20NQx1izS1koFMroKizLwShSItQ4P//6NNdRQMYwE)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

Uses a formula I got by [plugging sympy into my Python solution](https://tio.run/##HcxNCsIwEEDh/Zxidp3UWAVxU@hJxEWbHwzYyTCJYE4fi5u3@eBJq6/Mt97TLlkrlrZLA/AhYqRiZkBdroAxKzpMjGXW0@LOOrrL/bBQP8qoAKKJK0V6jP/DdHTL70LDajfrrLdhME8zha@s7MmY3n8).

```
5(/æ¦PO5(*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fVEP/8LJDywL8TTW0/v@PNtUx1DGMBQA)

$$
\sum_{A \subseteq X, A \ne \emptyset} (-5)^{1-\left| A \right|} \prod_{a\in A} a = -5  \sum_{A \subseteq X, A \ne \emptyset} \prod_{a\in A} {a \over -5}
$$

where \$X\$ is the multiset \$\left\{ x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\right\}\$.

```python
5(/         # divide each value by -5
   æ¦       # get all non-empty subsets
     P      # take the product of each subset
      O     # sum all values
       5(*  # multiply result by -5
```

---

A direct port of the Python answer is the same length:

```
Îv1y5/-*y+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cF@ZYaWpvq5Wpfb//9GmOoY6hrEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 29 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.reduce((a,b)=>a+b-a*b/5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQvSeZKTMihDZ6EXEx2hhFZfSj29t7C710xXM@7uYdSjLlM/ZTJ49PZACSAY2lOjRUhVZjiXm/8spqzRM44XovhdOy88KrjQ5gYxMwIpYf)

Based on [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
÷5CPC×5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wdlPnAOfD003///8fbaxjGAsA)

$$
5\times(1-\prod_{i=1}^n 1-{x_i \over 5})
$$

Read this from right to left to get the Jelly code. The formula is derived from the same sympy output as the 05AB1E answer. This has a nice symmetry to it as `C×5` is the inverse of `÷5C`.

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

Port of my Python answer

```
+_×÷5ɗɗ/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/187/vD0w9tNT04/OV3/////0aY6hrEA)

Comment: It would be nice to see some proper reasoning why this works, instead of *"this implements the correct formula"*. Maybe I'll find some time to think about this later.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
λ₌+*5/-;dR
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CE%BB%E2%82%8C%2B*5%2F-%3BdR&inputs=%5B5%2C1%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

port of 05AB1E answer’s formula

and also, wholesomely rekted by lyxal with 5 bytes saved

Comment: [13 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=5N%2F%E1%B9%97%E1%B8%A2%28n%CE%A0%29%E1%B9%A05N*&inputs=%5B5%2C1%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

Comment: [11 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=5N%2F%E1%B9%97%E1%B8%A2v%CE%A0%E2%88%915N*&inputs=%5B5%2C1%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

Comment: [10 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CE%BB%E2%82%8C%2B*5%2F-%3BdR&inputs=%5B5%2C1%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

Comment: [9 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CE%BB%E2%82%8C%2B*5%2F-%3BR&inputs=%5B5%2C1%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

Comment: (the 9 bytes is a port of Jelly)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
0ë{‼+*5/-
```

Port of [*@Yousername*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235275/52210), which is based on [*@ovs*' answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A64121+inquestion%3A235258).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/g8OrqRw17tLVM9XX//zfmMtUxBGEdQwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
0         # Start with 0
 ë        # Push the input-integers as float-array
  {       # Foreach over these floats:
   ‼      #  Apply the following two commands separated to the stack:
    +     #   Sum the top two values
    *     #   Multiply the top two values
     5/   #  Divide the product by 5
       -  #  And then subtract it from the sum
          # (after the loop, the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
≔⁰ηＦθ≧⁻×ι⊖∕η⁵ηＩη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcyxCsJADADQ3a/ImMAJOnTqJHYtiLiVDsc1NoH2qpezvx@Hzg9ekljSFhf3m5nOGS8BhNrTeyuAX4I@fg546iwVe80/C/DSlQ01QMep8Mq58oSd7joxSoCGiI7mUTRXvEerKESt@zA0Aa7j6Od9@QM) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @ovs' Python solution, except with a slightly rearranged formula `r-=c*(r/5-1)` which saves a byte when written in Charcoal.

```
≔⁰η
```

Start with zero heads.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop through the numbers of flips.

```
≧⁻×ι⊖∕η⁵η
```

Calculate the expected number of heads.

```
Ｉη
```

Output the expected number of heads.